# How to add Levels to TreeView

Tags: vb.net

Hey I am trying to add a Second level to a tree view the First level being GroupName and the Second level being Description

I have this code but is just creating separate nodes for each instead oh being under different Groups names

```
 Sub LoadGroupTree()
    '**Loads Property List
    ' Initialise Error Checking


    ' Dimension Local Variables
    Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim uPar As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim uNode As TreeNode
    '  Dim iGroupID As Integer = 0

    Dim uStackframe As New Diagnostics.StackFrame
    Try

        ' Check For Open Connection
        If uDBase Is Nothing Then
            OpenConnection()
            bConnection = True
        End If

        ' Run Stored Procedure - Load Property List (Based on Search Value)
        uCommand = New ADODB.Command
        With uCommand
            .ActiveConnection = uDBase
            .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandTimeout = 0
            uPar = .CreateParameter("@SearchValue", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
            .Parameters.Append(uPar)
            .Parameters("@SearchValue").Value = txtFilter.Text
            .CommandText = "InspsectionGroup_LoadRecords"
            uRecSnap = .Execute
        End With



        ' Suppress TreeView Repaint / Clear TreeView
        tvwInspectionGroups.BeginUpdate()
        tvwInspectionGroups.Nodes.Clear()
        tvwInspectionGroups.ShowNodeToolTips = True

        ' Populate List
 Do Until uRecSnap.EOF

            uNode = tvwInspectionGroups.Nodes.Add("P" & Format(uRecSnap("InspectionGroupID").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("GroupName").Value)
            uNode.Tag = "P:" & Format(uRecSnap("InspectionGroupID").Value, "0000") & ":01:"


            uNode.Nodes.Add("D" & Format(uRecSnap("GroupName").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("Description").Value)
            uNode.Tag = "D:" & Format(uRecSnap("GroupName").Value, "0000") & ":02:"


            uNode.Nodes.Add("A" & Format(uRecSnap("Description").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("AddressLine1").Value)
            uNode.Tag = "A:" & Format(uRecSnap("Description").Value, "0000") & ":03:"
            uRecSnap.MoveNext()
        Loop
        uRecSnap.Close()

        ' Repaint TreeView.
        tvwInspectionGroups.EndUpdate()
        tvwInspectionGroups.Refresh()

        ' Close Connection


    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Catch Error
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            WriteAuditLogRecord(uStackframe.GetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName, uStackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString, "Error", Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, 0)
            MsgBox("System Error Ref: " & sAuditID & vbCrLf & uStackframe.GetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName & " / " & uStackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace & Chr(13) & sErrDescription, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Business Management System - Unexepected Error Ref: " & sAuditID)
        End If

    Finally

        If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
        uRecSnap = Nothing

    End Try
```

Comment: You have to add the children to the uNode itself. uNode.Nodes.Add...  n the past, I've done this recursively if I didn't know how many levels I had.  If you have just one level of data, it will be easier for you. And...Why are you using classic ADO?!?!?

Comment: @Jeremy I have more than one Level I am trying to have 3 One down Group name to Description then again down to Addressline1 I thought I added it to my code

Comment: You are adding all items to the same child node. If you need more than one level, you need to store the node created at level 2, and add the child to that node.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoadGroupTree()
    '**Loads Property List
    ' Initialise Error Checking


    ' Dimension Local Variables
    Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim uPar As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim uNode As TreeNode
    Dim uNode3 As TreeNode

    '  Dim iGroupID As Integer = 0

    Dim uStackframe As New Diagnostics.StackFrame
    Try

        ' Check For Open Connection
        If uDBase Is Nothing Then
            OpenConnection()
            bConnection = True
        End If

        ' Run Stored Procedure - Load Property List (Based on Search Value)
        uCommand = New ADODB.Command
        With uCommand
            .ActiveConnection = uDBase
            .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandTimeout = 0
            uPar = .CreateParameter("@SearchValue", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
            .Parameters.Append(uPar)
            .Parameters("@SearchValue").Value = txtFilter.Text
            .CommandText = "InspsectionGroup_LoadRecords"
            uRecSnap = .Execute
        End With



        ' Suppress TreeView Repaint / Clear TreeView
        tvwInspectionGroups.BeginUpdate()
        tvwInspectionGroups.Nodes.Clear()
        tvwInspectionGroups.ShowNodeToolTips = True

        ' Populate List
 Do Until uRecSnap.EOF

            uNode = tvwInspectionGroups.Nodes.Add("P" & Format(uRecSnap("InspectionGroupID").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("GroupName").Value)
            uNode.Tag = "P:" & Format(uRecSnap("InspectionGroupID").Value, "0000") & ":01:"


            uNode3 = uNode.Nodes.Add("D" & Format(uRecSnap("GroupName").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("Description").Value)
            uNode.Tag = "D:" & Format(uRecSnap("GroupName").Value, "0000") & ":02:"


            uNode3.Nodes.Add("A" & Format(uRecSnap("Description").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("AddressLine1").Value)
            uNode3.Tag = "A:" & Format(uRecSnap("Description").Value, "0000") & ":03:"
            uRecSnap.MoveNext()
        Loop
        uRecSnap.Close()

        ' Repaint TreeView.
        tvwInspectionGroups.EndUpdate()
        tvwInspectionGroups.Refresh()

        ' Close Connection


    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Catch Error
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            WriteAuditLogRecord(uStackframe.GetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName, uStackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString, "Error", Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, 0)
            MsgBox("System Error Ref: " & sAuditID & vbCrLf & uStackframe.GetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName & " / " & uStackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace & Chr(13) & sErrDescription, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Business Management System - Unexepected Error Ref: " & sAuditID)
        End If

    Finally

        If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
        uRecSnap = Nothing

    End Try
```

Comment: NOTE: this is kind of un-elegant. if you have more levels to show, this will need to be changed. As mentioned above, if you are eventually showing parent/child information with an unknown number of levels, this should be converted to be recursive.